# JLD2: Saving/Loading structs with functions

Tags: julia

Is it possible to save/load structs that contain simple, one-line functions with JLD2?

Take the following example.

The script that saves the struct:

```
using JLD2
using Distributions

struct test_struct
    test_array
    test_fun
end

a = rand(5)
test_fun = () -> rand(Uniform(-5,5))

c = test_struct(a, test_fun)
@save "jld2-test.jld2" c
```

And the load script:

```
using JLD2
using Distributions

struct test_struct
    test_array
    test_fun
end

@load "jld2-test.jld2" c
c.test_fun()
```

This will result in an error. Only if I define `test_fun` in the loading script as well, it ll work. Is there some way to mitigate this and *really* save the struct with the function inside? Or are they alternatives that can deal with this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Aside from the fact that this is an interesting problem in a literal sense, it sounds like bad design. Why is it a problem to have functions defined in a (potentially separate) script and load them onto your workspace? The only scenario I can think of that you might want to have such a thing saved in a struct would be if you were trying to save closures or dynamically generated functions. And even then, I would be advising you against it, using struct member variables instead of closed ones, with appropriate dynamic-dispatch methods, instead of 'object-dispatched' ones.

Comment: My application for it is actually relatively close to this minimal example. I am doing some kind of Monte Carlo experiments and I would like to be able to save the functions that regenerates the samples. For some purposes it would just be enough to save the distribution object, but some are a bit more complicated and I would like to do something that is very general. I guess I could write a seperate struct for this purpose, but this is certainly a bit more complex than just saving/loading a relatively simple function.

Comment: DifferentialEquations.jl for example has functions as part of structs as well for the Ensemble/MonteCarlo problems (as far as I can see). I am not so sure how well these save/load with JLD2, though. I haven't tested it.

Comment: I agree it does seem like a limitation (/ bug?) of JLD2. Using `Serialization.serialize` and then `Serialization.deserialize`, for instance works as intended. (but unfortunately `Serialization` tends to come with all sorts of warnings and caveats regarding compatibility between different versions of Julia)

Comment: Yes, thanks. This could work, but I think Serialization is also not really optimal like you already stated. Especially, because I intend to publish the code later for other people to use and this also seems a bit error prone to me. I thought that there might be an "easy" solution that I was just not aware of, I only recently started using Julia.